# how to test against an SQLlite database for android

Tags: android, sqlite, junit

I am looking for a way to test against an sqllite database, I know that Mocks Objects can't do it.

What is the best possible way?

I have already tried to look into writing sql scripts to delete the data out of there, but that just cluttered my production code with test code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to actually test query your database, usually a separate test database is created, which mimics your 'real' database. Before each test, truncate the tables (and seed if necessary).

<sub>If you do not actually need to query your database, definitely use mocks. Create an interface and a class implementing it doing the actual queries, and mock the interface in your tests. Of course you need to test this implementing class, which you can do in the way described above.</sub>

Comment: for example, I want to make sure that correct data is being written to db